# How to remove extra margin above a Form

Tags: swift, swiftui, margin, ui-design, swiftui-form

I want part of my view to be wrapped inside a `Form`, but not the whole thing. I don't want the `Form` to take up that much space, so I've shrunken it using `.frame()`. Although there is still a lot of margin on top of the Form. Here's my code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                    Form {
                        Text("Some text in a form")
                    }
                        .frame(width: 400, height: 90) // shrinks Form size, but doesn't remove margin
         
                    Text("Some more text")
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `.frame()` height doesn't seem to remove that extra space at the top of the Form (light grey area).

[image: iPhone screenshot containing a Form with extra top margin]

I've also tried adding `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())` to the first `Text` view, but that doesn't remove the top margin. Any ideas?

Comment: I'am afraid this is not possible. You could consider developing your completely own solution, instead of using the built-in Form. A pro of that is that it gives you all flexibility, but a con is that it may take some time and maybe you can't get the same look as the rest of iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Form doesn't have a direct property to hide the header. For this, you need to use Section like below -

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ScrollView {
                VStack {
                     Form {
                        Section(header: VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
                           Text("Some text in a form").foregroundColor(Color.black).padding(.all, 6)
                        }) {
                            EmptyView()
                        }
                     }
                     .frame(width: 400.0, height: 40.0)
         
                    Text("Some more text")
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```